# How do I get connection pool in form / golang to an instance without database?

Tags: mysql, database, go

I have 10 databases in one instance. I want to take a single connection pool to the instance. From that connection I will trigger "use database" query before trigger any other query or I can build query with database name. Ex `select * from database.table`.

How do I get connection pool to instance without database in xorm or golang?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the DSN without selecting a database:

```
dsn := "root:@/"
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
```

and then use one of your suggestions. 
You can also create a 10-keys map between the databases' names and their corresponded `Db` object.

Comment: Is this possible in xorm?